# Replacing NAN value in a pandas dataframe from values in other records of same group

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a dataframe `df`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.nan, 1, 2,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan], 
               'B': [10, np.nan, np.nan,5,np.nan,np.nan,7], 
               'C': [1,1,2,2,3,3,3]})
```

which looks like :

```
     A     B  C
0  NaN  10.0  1
1  1.0   NaN  1
2  2.0   NaN  2
3  NaN   5.0  2
4  2.0   NaN  3
5  NaN   NaN  3
6  NaN   7.0  3
```

I want to replace all the NAN values in column `A` and `B` with the value from other records which are from the same group as mentioned in column `C`.

My expected output is :

```
     A     B   C
0  1.0   10.0  1
1  1.0   10.0  1
2  2.0    5.0  2
3  2.0    5.0  2
4  2.0    7.0  3
5  2.0    7.0  3
6  2.0    7.0  3
```

How can I do the same in pandas dataframe ?

Comment: Thanks for providing easy to reproduce question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with forward and back filling missing values:

```
df[['A','B']] = df.groupby('C')['A','B'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
print (df)

     A     B  C
0  1.0  10.0  1
1  1.0  10.0  1
2  2.0   5.0  2
3  2.0   5.0  2
4  2.0   7.0  3
5  2.0   7.0  3
6  2.0   7.0  3
```